# pg_restore: processing data for table "public.planet_osm_line" out of memory

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have made a dump of an open street map table and tried to restore it on another computer.

I already tried to tweak my Postgres settings but that didn't help.

Hope someone can help me out

**The command I used to restore it:**

```
pg_restore -Fc -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -W -d postgres -v /bin/planet_osm_line
```

the size of the "planet_osm_line" dump is 7.81GB

**Postgres.conf**

```
shared_buffers = 128MB
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
max_locks_per_transaction = 64 
max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64
```

**Hardware / OS**

OS: centos 7

postgres 9.5 + postgis 2.2

**(Memory) free -h**

MEM: Total:15G Used:258M

Swap: Total: 7.9G Used:4.9M

**(diskspace) df -h**

Size: 292G Used: 57G

Thanks

Comment: Was you who made the dump? If so, why didn't you do a plain text dump?

Comment: You need to increase `work_mem` (and `shared_buffers` wouldn't hurt although it doesn't matter for the import)